Inverse of a boolean lower unitriangular matrix
Is the inverse of a boolean lower unitriangular matrix identical to the matrix itself? The matrix entries are considered to be in GF(2), i.e. bool.

The motivation of this question is to counter chatgpt, which, depending on the context, can give grossly misleading answers.

No, and the smallest counterexamples are $3 \times 3$; for example WolframAlpha (much more reliable than ChatGPT!) will happily tell you that
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \equiv \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \bmod 2.$$
In general, the group of lower (or upper) unitriangular $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}_2$ is the Sylow $2$-subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_2)$, and it is a nilpotent group of nilpotency class $n-2$ or something like that. In particular it is not abelian for $n \ge 3$, but a group where every element squares to the identity is necessarily abelian (and so a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2)$.
You can see what's happening here more computationally by writing such a matrix as $I + N$ where $N$ is the strictly lower triangular part (which is nilpotent). Then we have $(I + N)^2 \equiv I + N^2 \bmod 2$ which is not $I$ if $N^2$ is nonzero $\bmod 2$, and this can happen for every $n \ge 3$.
In my experience most false facts about matrices have $2 \times 2$ counterexamples so it's interesting that it's necessary to go to $3 \times 3$ here.

That the smallest counter example is 3x3 might come from the fact that there are only 2 different lower unitriangular 2x2 bool matrices and one of them is the identity, which is its own inverse, and the other one is the only non-identity matrix of this kind, so it must also be its own inverse (because lower triangular has a lower triangular as its inverse and it cannot be the identity, so only itself is left as a candidate for its inverse.)
